# Cakephp Validation on a depending and shown field

Tags: validation, cakephp

I already found some examples here for my problem, but for some reason, they do not help me in my specific issue:

I have a form with a select 'type' with id's 1, 2, 3.
Depending on the selected value, I show/hide with jquery additional fields.

On option 1, only validate field 'question' and ignore 'picture' and 'answervalue'
On option 2 I need to have a 'picture' for upload selected, but ignore 'answervalue'
On option 3 have the field 'answervalue' which shouldn't be empty and ignore 'picture'

```
var $validate = array(
    'question' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => '{question} empty',
        ),
    ),
    'answervalue' => array(
        'rule' => array('checkCase', 'type'),
        'message' => '{answervalue} empty'
    ),
    'picture' => array(
        'picturecase' => array(
            'rule' => array('checkCase', 'type'),
            'message' => '{picture} empty'
        ),
        'uploadError' => array(
            'rule' => 'uploadError',
            'message' => '{picture} uploadError'
        )

    )
);
    function checkCase($data, $type) {
        if($type == 1) {
           return true;
        }
        if($type == 2 && empty($this->data[$this->alias]['picture'])) {
           return false;
        }
        if($type == 3 && empty($this->data[$this->alias]['answervalue'])) {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In my add.ctp I see all 3 fields as "required" (as long as I disable the jquery for how/hide).

I can't continue sending the form, as long as I do not fill into 'answervalue' any data.
Id 'answervalue' and 'question' filled with any data, I can submit the form and I do not get any validation errors.

I case of the 'picture' I get the upload error, but that is because I haven't any upload function done right now.

In general I think my check case is not working, or I have a general misunderstanding of it. Please have a look over it, I would like to understand what I am doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the validations from `$validate` and change the validation rules [dinamically](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules), depending on what was selected in the `type` select?

Function `checkCase` could do something like

```
$this->validator()->add('question', 'required', array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty'
));
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to come back to this. I tried but I can't get it working for my case, could you show me a simple example?

Comment: Did you try the examples from the documentation? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules  Basically, you would keep $validate empty, and just have a function that adds more rules.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working.
I removed the fields from $validate

```
var $validate = array(
        'question' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => '{question} empty',
            ),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'required' => 'create',
                'message' => '{question} exists',
            ),
        )
    );
```

I removed the checkCase function.
I added

```
function beforeValidate(){
    $type = $this->data[$this->alias]['type'];
    if($type == 3) {
            $this->validator()
                ->add('answervalue', 'required', array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => '{answervalue} empty',
                    'required' => 'create'
                ))
                ->add('answervalue', 'numeric', array(
                    'rule' => 'numeric',
                    'message' => '{answervalue} not numeric',
                    'required' => 'create'
            ));
        }


if($type == 2) {
     $this->validator()
            ->add('picture', 'extension', array(
                'rule' => array('extension', array('jpg', 'png')),
                'message' => '{picture} extension',
                'required' => 'create'
            ))
            ->add('picture', 'uploadfile', array(
                'rule' => array('uploadFile'),
                'message' => '{picture} upload error1',
                'required' => 'create'
            ))
            ->add('picture', 'uploadError', array(
                'rule' => 'uploadError',
                'message' => '{picture} upload error2',
                'required' => 'create'
            ));
        }
```

This Link: http://www.foldifoldi.com/?p=147 helped me a lot. Instead of notEmpty I use the extension validation, that does the trick with files.

Thanks a lot to everybody, it took me a while, but got it now!